# Related to Queryset Values()

Tags: python, django

This code works just fine. but its very slow. So I want to refactor following code.

```
from django.template.defaultfilters import date
json_resp = []
actions = Model.objects.all().select_related('user')

for action in actions:
    json_resp.append({
        'user': some_custom_function(user),
        'created_at': date(action.created_at, 'U')
    })
return HttpResponse(json.dumps(json_resp), content_type='application/json')



def some_custom_function(user):
    # return anonymous if there's no first name.
    if not user.first_name:
        return u'Anonymous'

    # if not last name, return first name.
    if not user.last_name:
        return u'{}'.format(user.first_name)

    # I can't use get_full_name().
    return u'{0} {1}.'.format(user.first_name, user.last_name[:1])
```

Refactor Code

```
actions = Model.objects.all().select_related('user').values(
    'user',
    'created_at'
).order_by('-created_at')
```

But there is a problem. what if I want to perform additional functionality with the fields? Can I do this with `values()`?

Like what I am doing in the first part. `'created_at': date(action.created_at, 'U')`.

Is there any better way? Thanks a lot.

**Edit:** I can move `some_custom_function` function in javascript. I only concern with `date` filter. I think I've to use [extra()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.extra)

Comment: I suppose that this code is slow because of the `some_custom_function(user)`. Can you show us the code of this function?

Comment: Added answer with refactored code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `__` relation in `values()` method.  To add more speed use `values_list()` instead of values, reduce formatting code and switch to list comprehension:

```
from datetime import datetime

def full_name(first_name, last_name):
    if not first_name:
        return u'Anonymous'
    if not last_name:
        return first_name
    return u'{0} {1}.'.format(first_name, last_name[:1])

def seconds_since_epoch(time):
    return int(time - datetime(1970, 1, 1)).total_seconds())

...

actions = Model.objects.all().select_related('user').values_list(
    'user__first_name', 'user__last_name', 'created_at'
).order_by('-created_at')

json_resp = [{'user': full_name(first_name, last_name),
              'created_at': seconds_since_apoch(created_at)}
             for fist_name, last_name, created_at in actions]
```